# How can i change a SELECT query using AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm very new to php and SQL so i'm really sorry if this is very trivial.
My site has multiple divs with table names inside it. The HTML is of the form:
`<p class="listname">(table name)</p>`

I am trying to write a function so that when a user clicks on a div, the function gets the text using innerHTML and the contents of that particular table are shown.
The jquery function i wrote is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".listname").click(function(){
var x=($(this).html()).toLowerCase(); //this assigns the text in the class listname to the variable x
console.log(x);

$.ajax({
     url: 'http://localhost/fullcalendar/events.php',
     data: {name:x},
     type: "GET",
     success: function(json) {

     }
});
});

});
```

And my PHP code is:

```
<?php

include 'ChromePhp.php';
ChromePhp::log('php running');

$json = array();
if($_POST['name']!=null)//check if any value is passed else use default value
{
    $table=$_GET['name'];

    ChromePhp::log($table);
}
else
{

    $table= 'event';

    ChromePhp::log($table);
}
$requete = "SELECT * FROM `$table` ORDER BY id";
try {
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fullcalendar', 'root', 'root');
} catch(Exception $e) {
exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}
// Execute the query
$resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

// sending the encoded result to success page
echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

?>
```

When i first load the website, the default value for $table is used in the query, and data is retrieved. However, when i try clicking on a div, the correct value is passed to php and assigned to $table (i checked in the console) but the data displayed is of the default table i.e 'event' table. 
How can i fix this?

PS: all my tables are in the same database.

Comment: Well, you're not doing anything in response to the AJAX call.  Notice your `success` function... It's empty.  Whatever you want to do with the data you get back from the server, that's where you do it.

Comment: Also note that this code is *wide open* to **SQL injection**.  You really shouldn't be blindly executing user input as SQL code.

Comment: An important note: **never** use data you receive from an untrusted source (e.g. the data submitted by the client), without escaping in your SQL query. Using `$_GET['name']`  without any escaping will allow SQL injections.

Comment: If the success function is empty, then how does it work for the first time with the default values? What i'm trying to do is get data from my table and display it on a calendar.

Comment: @monkeyD: `"how does it work for the first time with the default values?"` - That must be happening somewhere else.  Because an empty function literally does *nothing*.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking the POST data:

```
if($_POST['name']!=null)
```

But using GET data:

```
type: "GET"
```

So the `$_POST` array will always be empty and your `if` condition will always be `false`.  You probably meant to check the GET data:

```
if($_GET['name']!=null)
```

---

Also of note are a couple of other problems in this code:

1. Your `success` callback is empty, so this AJAX call isn't going to actually do anything client-side.  Whatever you want to do with the returned data needs to be done in that `success` function.
2. This code is *wide open* to **SQL injection**.  It's... very unorthodox to dynamically use table names like that.  And this is *probably* an indication that the design is wrong.  But if you *must* get schema object names from user input then you should at least be taking a white-list approach to validate that the user input is exactly one of the expected values.  **Never blindly execute user input as code.**